# Stripe Payment Link success link to include session id

Tags: stripe-payments

I can't seem to figure out how to include session id into stripe checkout success redirect.

I setup stripe check out payment link (from UI), I don't need anything fancy, just simple subscription. Once payment is successful, I would like to redirect customer to my WebApp, but I do need to include Stripe session id.

[image]

Unfortunate redirect includes literal {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}, instead of real `session id`. How can I mend it?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK Stripe doesn't support that right now. If you need something dynamic like that you'd have to integrate Checkout directly instead of simple PaymentLinks!

Comment: @karllekko you are correct. I spoke with tech. support and explained that `session id` would empower lots of simple and programming subscription scenarios. On the other hand: I'm trying to understand what is paymentlink currently good for? The only thing I can think of is testing or manual payment processing.

Comment: it works now. verified both in test and live modes

Comment: @galki that's great. Stripe finally added the feature :D